# Meteor - errors after upgrading

Tags: meteor, upgrade

Hi received the following error after upgrading to latest version:

W20150112-12:30:33.785(-5)? (STDERR)
W20150112-12:30:33.788(-5)? (STDERR) /Users/chazmee/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.37.1c4ifox++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:173
W20150112-12:30:33.788(-5)? (STDERR)                        throw(ex);
W20150112-12:30:33.788(-5)? (STDERR)                              ^
W20150112-12:30:33.789(-5)? (STDERR) ReferenceError: Router is not defined
W20150112-12:30:33.789(-5)? (STDERR)     at app/lib/router.js:1:36
W20150112-12:30:33.789(-5)? (STDERR)     at app/lib/router.js:69:3
W20150112-12:30:33.789(-5)? (STDERR)     at /Users/chazmee/placelist/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:175:10
W20150112-12:30:33.789(-5)? (STDERR)     at Array.forEach (native)
W20150112-12:30:33.790(-5)? (STDERR)     at Function.*.each.*.forEach (/Users/chazmee/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.37.1c4ifox++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
W20150112-12:30:33.790(-5)? (STDERR)     at /Users/chazmee/placelist/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:86:5
=> Exited with code: 8

Comment: Please specify details such as from which version to which one ?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error, it looks like you have a **Router** declaration, but it isn't defined.  I would recommend installing [iron router](https://atmospherejs.com/iron/router):

```
meteor add iron:router
```

Then reload your app.

Comment: ok yeah I'm getting more errors but at least now I get what's happening. Thanks. Uograding from 0.9.3 to 1.0

Comment: That fixed (well depends how you define fixed) it looks like now I've gotta redo a bunch of stuff. Ugh. Upgrade no bueno. Thanks for pointing me towards this though.

Comment: Would you consider accepting my answer?  Then you can ask a new question and I'll try to help. Just post the link here so I can review.  Thanks.

Comment: I'll post a new entry a bit later. Luckily it's only my local - my hosted app still works (which is good because I have about 50 people using it right now)

Comment: It worked - I had to re-configure some router stuff but turned out to be not such a big deal. But thanks for pointing me in the right direction.